# Python UnsatisfiableError trying to install PyInstaller

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller

I'm using Anaconda 3 with python 3.6 on Windows 10. When I try to install `pynstaller` into a virtual environment I have previously created I'm getting the following error message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - defaults/win-64::sqlite==3.26.0=he774522_0
  - defaults/win-64::wincertstore==0.2=py35hfebbdb8_0
  - pyinstaller
```

If I mark `sqlite` and `wincertstore` for removal anaconda will also remove many of the packages I need and there is no other version of `pyinstaller` which is compatible. Is it possible to install `pyinstaller` in another virtual environment but have it use the packages inside this environment? Any help solving this problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are the exact commands that you're using to retrieve and install `PyInstaller`?

Comment: I've tried the GUI package manager that comes with Anaconda and also tried the commend `conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller`